# Unable to connect to Bitbucket repository even after providing valid Repo URL and credentials from locally installed Jenkins

Tags: bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I have installed jenkins locally in my machine and trying to connect to the Bitbucket server where all my code resides

I have provided all the valid Repository URL and valid credentials.

Taken the Repo URL from the clone option present in the bitbucket and selected HTTPS option then copied from there by omitting the clone. its a valid URL.

i have double verified the credentials and its all correct and im able to login with those credetials in the bit bucket.[image]

I have tried to delete the credentials from the Jenkins and add it again. then tried all the possible ways but unable to connect to the repository.

Answer (score 2):

The URL could be valid but as stated in the error message on the screenshot it causes Git to prompt for the user input.

Just remove your `<username>@` from the repository URL.